# Trouble polling multiple IP addresses aiosnmp/asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, snmp

I'm trying to poll a large number of devices using aiosnmp/asyncio.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.    I'd like to feed a list of IP subnets to the "loop_over_ips" function.  Then use the ip address module to loop over every single IP address and add the that async "poll" function to the asyncio.gather pool.

Seems I've got two problems here.
First problem is that I'm not getting any responses.  The "res.value" is coming back as None even though devices in this range should be responding.
Second problem is that at a certain point the application is throwing a runtimeerror saying "cannot reuse already awaited coroutine".

Two questions then, how might I rewrite these functions to avoid the reuse of an  awaited coroutine?  Have I written these functions improperly leading to no devices responding?  With my code the way it is, is it even polling these devices?

```
import asyncio
import aiosnmp
import ipaddress

async def loop_over_ips(ip_addr_list: list) -> asyncio.gather():
    tasks = []
    for ip_addr in ip_addr_list:
        subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(ip_addr)
        for ip in subnet:
            ip = str(ip)
            tasks.append(poll(ip))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def poll(ip: str):
    with aiosnmp.Snmp(host=ip, community="Mycommunity") as snmp:
        try:
            for res in await snmp.get(".3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"):
            # for res in await snmp.walk():
                print(res.oid, res.value)
        except Exception:
            # print("Device did not respond")
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    infra_subnets = [
        "10.204.88.0/21",
        "10.201.7.0/24",
        "172.30.200.0/23",
        "172.30.210.0/23",
        "10.0.48.0/24",
        "10.1.20.0/24",
        "10.1.30.0/24",
        "10.1.32.0/24",
        "10.19.1.0/24",
        "10.98.1.0/24",
    ]
    asyncio.run(loop_over_ips(infra_subnets))
```

Comment: What's your actual question here? Is the code not working as you expect? If so, in what way does it fail?

Comment: @user4815162342 Good point, I have rewritten the question to hopefully make clear my issues.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `async with aiosnmp.Snmp(`?

Comment: @Pynchia Not according to the example at their [github start page](https://github.com/hh-h/aiosnmp) - strangely enough.

Comment: Did you get aiosnmp to work at all? Like, if you simplify the example by replacing `asyncio.gather(...)` with a simple for loop that just awaits `poll(ip)` in sequence? Or that just uses a single IP address, etc.? Perhaps you have a network misconfiguration or need to add extra parameters to the `Snmp` constructor? As for the "reuse awaited coroutine" error, I don't see anything obvious in your code to cause it. It might be a bug in aiosnmp, but I'd try to get fetching to work before reporting it. Perhaps things go wrong when an error causes aiosnmp to enter a less-well-tested code path.

Comment: @user4815162342 I tried what you said, I changed the last line of "loop_over_ips" from  await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  to just await poll(ip).  Its still causing an error.  It iterates a few times and silently must be failing.  I don't get any tracebacks but the script exists quickly after polling a few addresses.  I know that I'm getting some sort of response from a few devices though, any devices that are up will actually hit my print statement and print out the res.oid and res.value (which ends up being None).  Devices that timeout are just hitting the except block.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in aiosnmp. I'd try to report it to the devs.

Answer (score 0):

aiosnmp maintainer here, sorry I didn't notice your question but will answer anyway, see my comments in the code below

```
import asyncio
import aiosnmp
import ipaddress


async def loop_over_ips(ip_addr_list: list) -> None:
    tasks = []  # you should move tasks below first for loop
    for ip_addr in ip_addr_list:
        subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(ip_addr)
        for ip in subnet:
            ip = str(ip)
            tasks.append(poll(ip))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # or move gather outside first loop, it caused RuntimeError


async def poll(ip: str):
    async with aiosnmp.Snmp(host=ip, community="Mycommunity") as snmp:  # in the recent version it should be async with
        try:
            for res in await snmp.get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"):  # oid should start with .1 or 1, not 3
                print(res.oid, res.value)
        except Exception:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    infra_subnets = [
        "10.204.88.0/21",
        "10.201.7.0/24",
        "172.30.200.0/23",
        "172.30.210.0/23",
        "10.0.48.0/24",
        "10.1.20.0/24",
        "10.1.30.0/24",
        "10.1.32.0/24",
        "10.19.1.0/24",
        "10.98.1.0/24",
    ]
    asyncio.run(loop_over_ips(infra_subnets))
```